# How do I access horizon for openstack from host on same networks as server LAN address

Tags: networking, iptables, openstack

So I have installed a clean version of Ubuntu 16.04 and installed openstack via conjure-up.

[Conjure-up_Complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTZb5.png)

My pc is on 192.168.1.1/24

Server Nic is 192.168.1.2/24

Horizon is at 10.135.16.58/24 (the virtual network)

I need to setup NAT to forward a request to the Virtual Network.

I understand i need to utilize IPTABLE to do so.

Ive tried to use the following rule:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.2 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.135.16.58
```

But I still can not hit horizon from my pc.

Comment: Did you enable forwarding in sysctl.conf. `'echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf'` ?

Answer (score 1):

'echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf'